# Convert 7 digit Julian Date to DateTime in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, julian-date

I have seen numerous examples on the web and a few here on SO. However, none seem to work for my data. Here are a few julian dates with their known converted values.

```
JUL | DateTime
2454522 | 2008-02-25 00:00:00.000
2454571 | 2008-04-14 00:00:00.000
2455713 | 2011-05-31 00:00:00.000
```

I have tried this which does not work:

```
DECLARE @JD int = 2454522
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, @JD / 1000 - 1900, @JD % 1000 - 1)
```

It gives me this: 2455-06-06 00:00:00.000 which is obviously wrong. What am I missing here? Thanks ind advance.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for?

Comment: The conversion between a Julian date and YMD is not that trivial. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day for an explanation and an algorithm to compute one from the other.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: Given the use of `@` to indicate a variable name, it looks like SQLServer.

Comment: @David Sorry, for SQL

Comment: BBauer42: SQL (an abbreviation for Structured Query Language) is a language used to manipulate data held in a Relational Database Management System (RDBMS for short). There are many RDBMSs (such as Oracle, MySQL, Microsoft SQLServer, PostgreSQL and so on), each of which have their own version of SQL. David was asking which of these was being used - it's significant, because each dialect of SQL tends to have its own way of dealing with dates, different from the others. I deduced that you are using SQLServer - can you confirm whether this is true, and if not, which version of SQL you are using?

Comment: My apologies, SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach that should work in SQLServer:

```
select @jd, dateadd(d,@jd - 2440588,'1970-01-01')
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bfcdc/4).

Answer (score 1):

As long as your DBMS supports some set of scalar functions capable of computing the number of days between
two dates and can add a number of days to a given date, all you need to do is compute some sort of normalization
value for Julian Dates and the do some fairly simple date math.

In a DB/2 environment the relevant functions are: DAYS and DATE. start with some base date you know the Julian date of. 
For example the Julian date for 2000-01-01 is: 2451545.

Next use the DAYS/DATE scalar functions to compute an integer value of the same date. The query to do this in DB/2 is:

```
select days(date('2000-01-01'))
from sysibm.sysdummy1
;
```

The result of this query is: 730120

Use these two values to compute a normalization factor for Julian Dates: 2451545 - 730120 = 1721425

Now you can compute the Gregorian Date from an Julian Date as follows:

```
select date(juliandate - 1721425)
from sysibm.sysdummy1
;
```

Using the examples from your question:

```
select date(2454522 - 1721425),
       date(2454571 - 1721425),
       date(2455713 - 1721425)
from sysibm.sysdummy1
;
```

Returns the following dates: 2008-02-25  2008-04-14  2011-05-31

Your DBMS may not support the specific scalar functions used in the above example, however, most will support
some mechanism of adding some number of days from a Gregorian Date and determining the number of days between
two dates. You should be able to devise some workable formula using these functions and a normalization factor for Julian Dates
as illustrated above.

Answer (score 0):

These are Astronomical Julian Date values, whole days only. The quick and dirty conversion to *datetime* in SQL Server (which of course cannot go below the year 1753) would be:

```
DECLARE @jd as int = 2454522
SELECT CAST(@jd - 2415021 as datetime)

2008-02-25 00:00:00.000
```

*2415021* comes from the following:

```
SELECT CAST(0 as datetime)

1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

And according to the at [Julian Date converter](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php), 1900-01-01 CE is *2415020.5*. Add 0.5 to that because the [astronomical Julian Date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) starts from noon, and we are dealing with whole days only.

If you do not like dirty, try this one:

```
DECLARE @jd as int = 2454522
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, @jd - 2415021, '1900-01-01')

2008-02-25 00:00:00.000
```