# Convert Julian Date to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql, sql-server, julian-date

I have searched far and wide, but I can't seem find a way to convert julian to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Here is the format of my julian:

The Julian format consists of the year, the first two digits, and the day within the year, the last three digits.

For example, `95076` is `March 17, 1995`. The `95` indicates the year and the
`076` indicates it is the 76th day of the year.

```
15260
```

I have tried this but it isn't working:

```
dateadd(d,(convert(int,LAST_CHANGED_DATE) % 1000)-1, convert(date,(convert(varchar,convert(int,LAST_CHANGED_DATE) /1000 + 1900) + '/1/1'))) as GrgDate
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert 7 digit Julian Date to DateTime in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279457/convert-7-digit-julian-date-to-datetime-in-sql)

Comment: no, that jd is different than the one i am trying to convert.  I tried this and it didn't work

Comment: Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can select each part of the date using `datepart()`

```
SELECT DATEPART(yy, 95076), DATEPART(dy, 95076)
```

+++EDIT: I misunderstood something. Here's my correction: +++++

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, CAST(RIGHT('95076',3) AS int) – 1, CONVERT(datetime,LEFT('95076',2) + '0101', 112))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: leaving this answer for Oracle and MySQL users**
This will not work in T-SQL.

Use this:

```
MAKEDATE(1900 + d / 1000, d % 1000)
```

For example:

```
SELECT MAKEDATE(1900 + 95076 / 1000, 95076 % 1000)
```

This returns `March, 17 1995 00:00:00`.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/29294)

Comment: MAKEDATE() is Oracle and MySql only. It is not part of the standard.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn You are correct. I'll leave this here in case a MySQL or Oracle user comes along.

Answer (score 0):

I concatenated 20 to my JD and then ran 
`DATEADD(YEAR, LAST_CHANGE_DATE / 1000 - 1900, LAST_CHANGE_DATE % 1000 - 1)`

this got me the result.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

**FOR SQL Users**

  `DECLARE @jdate VARCHAR(10)
  SET @jdate = 117338
  SELECT dateadd(dd, (@jdate - ((@jdate/1000) * 1000)) - 1, dateadd(yy, @jdate/1000, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work in all case.

```
DECLARE @date int
SET @date = 21319
SELECT DATEADD(dd, RIGHT(@date,LEN(@date)-3)-1, DATEADD(yy,LEFT(@date,1)*100 +RIGHT(LEFT(@date,3),2),'1 Jan 1900'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify 1 or 0 for century in first character.  For example, `SET @date = 21319` should be prefixed with 1 or 0. Below is an example that will work with all y2k use cases.

```sql
DECLARE @jdate INT 
SET @jdate = 119150 
SELECT DATEADD(dd, (@jdate - ((@jdate/1000) * 1000)) - 1, DATEADD(yy, @jdate/1000, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare @Julian varchar(7)

Declare @date date

Set @Julian = 2020277

Set @Date = Dateadd(day,+ Cast(right(@Julian,3) as int)-1, Cast(left(@Julian,4) + '0101' as Date))

Select @Date

Comment: This question was answered four years ago. While your answer isn't identical to the accepted answer, it is quite close. Can you edit your answer to provide an explanation for why this approach is preferred over the accepted answer? Or, at least, under what conditions a reader might want to use your approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL is simple (you can do similar for 2 digit year YYMMDD)

Declare `@julDate int = 2020275`

```sql
Select 
DateAdd
(
   day
   , Right(@julDate,3)-1
   , Cast((Left(@julDate,4)+'-01-01') as smalldatetime)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
DECLARE @jdate int

SET @jdate = 21243

select dateadd(dd, (@jdate - ((@jdate/1000) * 1000)) - 1, dateadd(yy, @jdate/1000+100, 0))
```