# convert julian format date into YYYYMMDD format

Tags: sql

How can i convert julian format date into YYYYMMDD format.

for example :
2016223081623

2016225031241

Comment: The answer totally depends on which database you are using.  Which database are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550260/sql-server-convert-julian-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this helps u..

```
DECLARE @JDATE VARCHAR(100)='2016225031241'

SELECT DATEADD(DD, CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(@JDATE, 3)) - 1 ,
CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(@JDATE,1,2)+'0101', 212)) AS [JULIAN DATE]
```

For YYYYMMDD format.

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),DATEADD(DD, CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(@JDATE, 3)) - 1,
CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(@JDATE,1,2)+'0101', 212)),112) AS [JULIAN DATE]
```

Comment: A very product specific answer, to a question with no dbms tagged. At least tell OP and the rest of us which dbms this is for.